# Why spring data jpa repositories force interfaces only?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am setting up a multi-module spring-boot project having the following structure:

- root

  - core(having class TestingHandler, injecting TestingRepository to save data)
  - persistence-api(having custom repository interface TestingRepository)
  - persistence-memory(having MemoryTestingRepository abstract class extending both TestingRepository and JpaRepository)
  - main(having the entry point of the application and a runner which invokes the TestingHandler to save the data)

I am trying to build a simple spring boot application which will persist a sample record in its h2 in-mem db. but i keep getting the following error:

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.****.***.services.testing.persistence.memory.MemoryTestingRepository' in your configuration.
```

What am i missing?

I have tried the following:

- Not using repository hierarchy. Just using a single interface which extends `JpaRepository` and it works but i have to have interface hierarchy due to custom methods and need to support multiple db implementations in future.
- tried using the MemoryRepository directly in TestingHandler, did not work. If i convert the MemoryRepository to interface (and get rid of custom methods), it works. but like i mentioned i need to have custom method an have to support the interface hierarchy to support legacy code.
- tried playing a lot with Annotations like @EnableJpaRepositories, @ComponentScan etc, no help.
- Testing.java is pretty standard POJO with @Entity and @Id annotation, very simple.

Here is the Handler class:

```
package com.***.**.services.testing.core;

@Service
public class TestingHandler {

    @Autowired
    private TestingRepository testingRepository;

    @NotNull
    public Testing create(@NotNull final TestingDto testingDto) {
        Testing testing = new Testing("123", testingDto.getName(), testingDto.getDescription(), testingDto.Key(), testingDto.getVersion());
        testingRepository.create(testing);
        return testing;
    }
}
```

Note it is injecting the interface TestingRepository.

Here is the TestingRepository interface (plain and simple):

```
package com.***.**.services.testing.persistence.api;

@Repository
public interface TestingRepository {
  void create();
  void findByCustomAttr();
}
```

Here is the impl class of TestingRepository:

```
package com.***.**.services.testing.persistence.memory;

@Repository
public abstract class MemoryTestingRepository implements JpaRepository<Testing, Integer>, TestingRepository {
 @Override
    public void create(@NotNull Testing testing) {
        save(testing); //the real jpa method called.
    }

@Override
public void findByCustomAttr(){
//some impl....
}

}
```

finally, the main class looks like this:

```
package com.***.**.services.testing.main;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.***.**.services.testing")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.***.**.services.testing.persistence")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.***.**.services.testing.persistence"})
public class TestingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

i also have a runner class which invokes the handler method:

```
package com.***.**.services.testing.main;

@Component
public class TestingService implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private TestingHandler testingHandler;

    @Override

    public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
        test();
    }


    public void test() {
        testingHandler.create(new TestingDto("name", "desc", "some_mapping_id", Version.create()));
    }

}
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MemoryTestingRepository` is abstract, thus it can't be instantiated by Spring. Also repositories interfaces are managed by Spring Data Jpa and you shouldn't have that dependency in your core module.

From my (I admit little) experience in multi module projects, I currently create SAM interfaces in my core module for every data-provider request. Then implement those interfaces in a concrete data-provider class in my data-provider module, injecting the wanted JpaRepository.

In your case that means:

**Core module:**

```java
@Service
public class TestingHandler {

    @Autowired
    private TestingCreator testingCreator;

    @NotNull
    public Testing create(@NotNull final TestingDto testingDto) {
        Testing testing = ...;
        testingCreator.createTesting(testing);
        return testing;
    }

}
```

```java
public interface TestingCreator {

    void createTesting(Testing testing);

}
```

**Persistance module**

```java
@Repository
public class TestingDataprovider implements TestingCreator /*, ...other interfaces from core module*/ {

    @Autowired
    private TestingRepository testingRepository;

    @Override
    public void createTesting(Testing testing) {
        testingRepository.save(testing);
    }

    // other methods like findByCustomAttr

}
```

```java
public interface TestingRepository extends JpaRepository<Testing, Integer> {
    // custom methods
}
```

In this way you're also decoupling your core entities from your persistance entities.

---

For reference, the most useful guide I found is [this github repository](https://github.com/mattia-battiston/clean-architecture-example) with an excelent README with other useful links.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Though it will help achieve clean separation of layers. but it does not solve the problem i have. in your case, i will have to create MemoryTestingRepository which will provide the impl of methods declared in TestingRepository. but if i make MemoryTestingRepository a class it will force to implement JpaRepository methods as well which i dont want. so the only choice i am left with is abstract class which "like you said" cannot be instantiated. what other choice do i have ?

Comment: The point is you don't have a MemoryTestingRepository, but a TestingDataprovider which will just call TestingRepository interface methods (no logic other that entity convertion/mapping). Just let Spring handle the repository implementation.

Comment: @vikeshpandey if I'm not wrong, your intent is **not** to customize your base repository (add or change the normal logic of JpaRepository) but just refer to your repository from core module. IMHO, this answer provides you a way to achieve this without increasing complexity of persistance module (or at least I find this _less_ complex than Joao answer)

Comment: yes you are right. i dont want to override JpaRepo impls provided. The problem i have is i cannot introduce providers as i have to change the archetype being followed by org. the archetype is mentioned in the question where we have persistence-api and persistence-memory, similarly we will have persistence-postgres and persistence-mongo in future as submodules to support multiple dbs. any way to achieve this with the current module structure i have?

Comment: i am able to make it work !!! :). I just created the dataprovider specific for Memoryimpl and injected the MemoryTestingRepository into it and it worked. In future, i will have different data providers for different database impl. Basically i slightly tweaked your suggestion. the TestingCreator becomes TestingRepository and TestingRepository becomes MemoryTestingRepository and i have the provider binding it all together. thanks again. i am going to mark your suggestion as answer.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that not only your MemoryTestingRepository doesn't implement the TestingRepository interface but is also abstract, that is a bit confusing to me. Is that the actual code or you made some editing mistake when posting? 
If it is then the answer might be that Spring might have trouble creating a bean from an abstract class.

Check the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior
as it explains how to set up custom repository implementations

EDIT:
Based on your comment and update I understand your issue now.

what you want is to have your concrete repository extend SimplaJpaRepository so that your implementation can have access to save method of JpaRepository.

check out an example in https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.customize-base-repository

your repository would look something like this

```
package com.***.**.services.testing.persistence.memory;

@Repository
public class MemoryTestingRepository extends SimpleJpaRepository<Testing, Integer> implements TestingRepository {
 @Override
    public void create(@NotNull Testing testing) {
        save(testing); //the real jpa method called.
    }

@Override
public void findByCustomAttr(){
//some impl....
}

}
```

Comment: Yes that was an editing mistake. i have fixed it in the code sample. As it is extending JpaRepository and TestingRepository, it can neither be a concrete class nor an interface(as it does not want to redefine JpaRepo.. method but wants to define the TestingRepo.. methods)..

Comment: i tried following the approach suggested by you. The above repo class would force to have a contstructor. when i add it like : `    public MemoryTestingRepositoryImpl(final Class<Testing> domainClass,
                                       final EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
    }`
it cannot autowire testing class. No bean of Type Testing found. the IDE itself shows this error. Testing.java is annotated with @Entity though.